# Pivot table of student location information

Tags: postgresql, pivot

I have a table that records the names of students and the continent they are from.

For example:

| name | continent |
| --- | --- |
| Michael | America |
| Steve | Europe |
| Jo | Africa |
| Paul | Europe |
| Mike | Africa |
| Frankie | Africa |

Now I want to pivot the continent column in the `Student` table so that each name is **sorted alphabetically** and displayed underneath its corresponding continent. The output headers should be Africa, America, and Europe, respectively.

That means the output should be:

| Africa | America | Europe |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Frankie | Michael | Paul |
| Jo | null | Steve |
| Mike | null | null |

I tried the following query and got the expected answer.

```
select Africa,America,Europe 
from(
    select row_number() over(order by name) as rn,name as Africa from student
    where continent='Africa'
) a
left join(
    select row_number() over(order by name) as rn,name as America from student
    where continent='America'
) b on a.rn=b.rn
left join(
    select row_number() over(order by name) as rn,name as Europe from student
    where continent='Europe'
) c on a.rn=c.rn
```

But I found that if I **don't know in advance which continent has the most students**, this method won't work.

For example:

| name | continent |
| --- | --- |
| Michael | America |
| Steve | Europe |
| Jo | Africa |
| Paul | Europe |

For this table, I will get the following results(**the Europe column is missing 'Steve'**):

| Africa | America | Europe |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Frankie | Michael | Paul |

So I want to ask what method should be used in this kind of situation?(By the way, I use the `PieCloudDB` Database which is compatible with PostgreSQL)

Comment: You'd use a `FULL JOIN` then. What do you mean by "compatible"?

Comment: I mean  that you can use PostgreSQL syntax (because not everyone knows the database I am using)

Comment: Then you should be able to use a standard conforming `FULL JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following in your pieclouddb database.

Use `max()` or `min()`, and use `row_number() over()` for group.(Tested on PostgreSQL)

```
select
max(case when continent = 'Africa' then name end) as Africa,
max(case when continent = 'America' then name end) as America,
max(case when continent = 'Europe' then name end) as Europe
from (
select *, row_number() over(partition by continent order by name) rn
from student )a
group by rn
```